# Async cassandra queries

Tags: asynchronous, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

I've been trying to update an app to enhance performance, it uses Datastax Cassandra Java Driver for DAL services.

Now, I need to convert sync queries to async queries, I didn't find satisfactory answers to my doubts (at least not on the web pages I visited).

Could anybody please answer the below queries or refer to a link where I could get an answer.

1> What are the possible problematic scenarios I need to worry about before changing synced executes to ansync execs?

2> How will reads and writes behave, can I change one of them without worrying about any issues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Asyn queries references:
1) https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries 
2) https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/async/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that you need to think about:

- You need to rate limit your code - by default it's only 1024 request per connection, so you may need to [increase this number](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/pooling/#simultaneous-requests-per-connection). But even with increased number of request per connection it's easy to overload Cassandra, so you still need to control it, with something like [this](https://github.com/alexott/datastax-vehicle-demo/blob/code-optimizations/src/main/java/com/datastax/demo/SessionLimiter.java);
- You need correctly handle errors - you may need to add error handler to promise that is returned, and react correspondingly;
- You need correctly create statements - for example, don't reuse the same `BoundStatement` as it's not thread safe;
- don't re-use same List/Set/Map instances that you pass as parameters, etc.

Comment: Thanks Alex, one more thing, how exactly does pairing batch statements with executeAsync work, given that batches maintain atomicity. Can I combine them to get a better performance without losing atomicity?

Comment: there are different types of batches - you can batch for multiple tables, you can batch for same table, etc. If you batch for same partition inside table, then it's much faster than sending the same queries multiple times. But otherwise, use of batches with `executeAsync` is the same as with `execute`...

Comment: great! made it perfectly clear, well in my case the batch is for multiple tables, so I think using executeAsync is useless.

Comment: Why, it's still useful, as you can still parallelize execution, without adding more threads. But you really need to think about use of batches - they are quite expensive, and should be used only in limited amount of cases

Comment: Using batches to ensure the atomicity of the transaction. The initial code that I wrote was to process the batch in async fashion. I have multiple transactions, each with a set of upserts. So, rather than executing batch for each of them in a synced manner, I am trying to use async with each batch to get better performance. Makes sense, right?

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks a million!